# Sort List within Map in scala

Tags: scala

I have a map like:

```
val v = Map("01" -> List(34,12,14,23), "11" -> List(22,11,34))
```

I simply can't find a way to sort the list items within map.

I tried like:

```
v.flatMap(v => v._2.sortBy(list => list._))
```

but seems that it does not sort list items.

Does anybody know where I am wrong?

**UPDATE**: Actually my List are List of tuples like `List[(Object1, Object2, Object3, Object4)]`, I put `int` for simplicity. (but I think `_.sorted` will not work for my objects case). So I basically want to sort by one of this objects column. (for instance `Object1.int`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
v.mapValues(_.sorted)
// Map(01 -> List(12, 14, 23, 34), 11 -> List(11, 22, 34))
```

If your values are tuples, try this:

```
v.mapValues(_.sortBy(_._1))
```

This approach will also work for classes, just say e.g. `_.sortBy(_.age)`.

---

Or if you want one, merged list:

```
v.values.flatten.toSeq.sorted
// List(11, 12, 14, 22, 23, 34, 34)
```

(for list of tuples):

```
v.values.flatten.toSeq.sortBy(_._1)
```

Comment: Is there any way to insert in this List of tuples another element on the fly? I mean without creating new map?

Comment: @CristianBoariu: you can use `mapValues()` as well to map from one tuple to another. Feel free to open another question to make it clearer.

Comment: This doesn't sort in place. Is there any way to do this instead of setting it equal to a new map? Or would this be bad practice?

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean like this?

```
val v = Map("01" -> List(34,12,14,23), "11" -> List(22,11,34))
//v: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,List[Int]] = Map(01 -> List(34, 12, 14, 23), 11 -> List(22, 11, 34))

v map { case (k, v) => (k -> v.sorted) }
//res0: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,List[Int]] = Map(01 -> List(12, 14, 23, 34), 11 -> List(11, 22, 34))
```

**Edit** or:

```
v mapValues (_ sorted)
//res1: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,List[Int]] = Map(01 -> List(12, 14, 23, 34), 11 -> List(11, 22, 34))
```

**Another edit:**

If there's an implicit `Ordering` in scope for all the types in your tuples, it should work exactly the same way:

```
val v = Map(
  "01" -> List((34, "thirty-four"), (12, "twelve"), (14, "fourteen"), (23, "twenty-three")), 
  "11" -> List((22, "twenty-two"), (11, "eleven"), (34, "thirty-four")))
//v: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,List[(Int, String)]] =
//Map(
//  01 -> List((34,thirty-four), (12,twelve), (14,fourteen), (23,twenty-three)), 
//  11 -> List((22,twenty-two), (11,eleven), (34,thirty-four)))

v mapValues (_ sorted)
//res3: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,List[(Int, String)]] =
//Map(
//  01 -> List((12,twelve), (14,fourteen), (23,twenty-three), (34,thirty-four)),
//  11 -> List((11,eleven), (22,twenty-two), (34,thirty-four)))
```

If you want to sort only by one member of the tuple (say ... in this case the second one):

```
v mapValues (_ sortBy (_ _2))
//res5: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,List[(Int, String)]] =
//Map(
//  01 -> List((14,fourteen), (34,thirty-four), (12,twelve), (23,twenty-three)),
//  11 -> List((11,eleven), (34,thirty-four), (22,twenty-two)))
```

Comment: or may be `v mapValues { _.sorted }`